# Invoking an Angular click event from browser console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm inspecting the DOM on an Angular application and seeing a simple link such as the following:

```
<button type="button" class="button mini text right clear-all" ng-show="draft.roster.slotsFilled" ng-click="draft.resetRoster()" really="Are you sure you want to clear all players from your team?">
```

I wanted to try to invoke the `ng-click` command here directly into the browser console by simply pasting `draft.resetRoster();` Unfortunately I'm getting `draft is not defined` when trying to access it through the console. The link works perfectly fine itself though.

What's the best way to access/invoke the code that the `ng-click` attribute is referencing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-click` just registers a click event only so you could literally fire a click event from console by selecting the element. Example:-

Say your button can be uniquely identified by all these css classes, you could do:

```
//You could use jquery as well if it is available, here some vanilla accessors.
document.querySelector('.button.mini.text.right.clear-all').click();
//If you have multiple, use querySelectorAll and 
//select the respective element or if you have an Id:
document.getElementById('#myButton').click();
```

or you can use extensions like batarang (chrome) to access the scope directly or get the scope of the element using

```
angular.element(elementRefGotFromOneOfTheAboveWays).scope().draft.resetRoster();`
```

and if you want to see change reflected in DOM you would need to call `scope.$apply()` manually, i.e

```
var scope = angular.element(elementRefGotFromOneOfTheAboveWays).scope();
scope.draft.resetRoster();
scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome, install the [angular batarang extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en), then simply right click on the element, click "Inspect element" and in the console type:

```
$scope.draft.resetRoster()
```

If you have methods in an angular service that you'd like to call, you can access the service by doing:

```
service = angular.element(document).injector().get('NameOfServiceHere')
service.somePropertyOrMethod()
```